# Call Spring MVC method with Integer argument in EL, argument comes in as null

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, el

I've tried the following expressions in my JSP (assume `row_rowNum` is a variable), including a Constant, but am getting NullPointers.

```
<c:if test="${incompleteIndicator(0)}">  
<c:if test="${incompleteIndicator(row_rowNum - 1)}"> 
<c:if test="${incompleteIndicator(${row_rowNum - 1})}">
```

Spring MVC Controller method:

```
@ModelAttribute
public boolean getIncompleteIndicator(Integer index)
{
    System.out.println("called getIncompleteIndicator with index = " + index);
    if (index == 1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

But the parameter Index always comes in as NULL, never as as integer, even for the constant. What am I doing wrong?

Output for all cases:

```
called getIncompleteIndicator with index = null
```

Comment: I don't do Spring MVC, but I do EL and I can tell numbers in EL are by default resolved as `Long`, not as `Integer`. Try changing method argument from `Integer` to `Long` to see if that makes Spring MVC happy.

Comment: Is incompleteIndicator the function name or getIncompleteIndicator?